# Center a google chart in the browsers printer version

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

[image]

Greetings, I have a html page with a google chart and I want it to be centered horizontally. I used margin: 0 auto for the div of the chart. It is in the middle on the screen version in Chrome and the image is showing what I am getting in the printer version which is not pretty.

`<div style="margin: 0 auto" id="maChart"></div>`

What can I do to center the google chart in the middle? If possible, I am hoping to know a way that works on multiple main browsers eg. safari, chrome, edge, and IE.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the width of #maChart div?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Kevin Caravaggio I just tried wrapping the div with bootstrap in html and giving the width in % in its css. I don't think it is exactly positioned at the center but definitely it looks better than the previous one. The main concern of mine is that it will look differently in different browsers.

> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
>   <div class="col-md-10">
>     <div style="margin: 0 auto" id="maChart"></div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>  
> </div>
> ```

In the css,

> ```
>   #maChart{
>     width: 65%;   
>  }
> ```